# SOQL on EmailMessage does not return all records

Tags: apex, soql

I am performing SOQL on EmailMessage standard object without any condition. The query returns less records than actual count. The class which runs the query does not have with sharing keyword. But when I run the same query in query editor from Developer Console it returns all the records as expected. Why is this happening?
Below is the query

```
SELECT Id, Status FROM EmailMessage
```

Comment: Can you add some code of how you are doing this?

Comment: Added the query in question description.